# C++: Casting my object to a different superclass results in a different pointer address

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, polymorphism

I'm learning C++, trying to write good, polymorphic code, and running in to some confusion. I have a class Er_1Sine which has two superclasses: "Generator" and "Triggerable".

Er_1Sine looks like this:

```
class Er_1Sine : public Generator, public Triggerable{

}
```

If I create a "Generator" pointer (gen), setting it to "er1", the pointer address matches the address of "er1". However, the address of my "Triggerable" pointer, "trig", doesn't match. What's going on here? is trig not pointing to the same object that er1 and gen are?

```
er1 = new Er_1Sine();   
Generator *gen = er1;
Triggerable *trig = er1;

printf("\n\n er1 as Er_1Sine: %p \n", er1);
// outputs: "er1 as Er_1Sine: 0x4d28920"

printf("er1 as Generator address: %p \n", gen);
// outputs: "er1 as Generator address: 0x4d28920"   

printf("er1 as Triggerable address: %p \n\n", trig);
// outputs: er1 as Triggerable address: 0x4d289f8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while not *entirely* correct, you can think of your compound class as 2 seperate objects stacked on top of eachother.  The one you declared first being the top (same address) and the one declared second underneath (hence a different address).

Answer (score 5):

This is multiple inheritance - base class sub-objects are at different offsets withing the child instance, thus different addresses. It's the compiler front-end that has to adjust the pointer values during the implicit upcasts.

Comment: I would also add that, for this very reason, you probably should not be doing == on pointer values to determine equality. It's probably better to take a Java-like approach and write an equality function or operator.

Comment: Hmm, yes and no. Comparing pointers is a built-in operation, you cannot override that. Comparing instances most probably needs a custom set of operators. Nothing Java-like here ... :)

Comment: Actually using == for pointer equality is typically perfectly fine for determinating if they point to the same object, since if I'm reading the standard correctly, pointers can only be compared when they are the same type (after possible type conversions), so in this case when comparing a base class pointer to a derived class one, the later would be implicitely casted to base class (and therefore be adjusted accordingly), so it would compare true if both originate from the same derived object.

Comment: @Grizzly In times past, I've experienced segfaults from improper casting before a function that interally does a comparison with == and != was called (crash didn't happen at comparison, but in logic that follwoed). I think I spoke rash. I do ptr == comparisons very frequently, but if it's in an API function that I can't control the calling context, I'd rather take the approach of writing a class member to determine equality. This function can be shadowed in derived classes but should not be virtual. This gets messy too though, because derived needs to remember to call parent equality function.

Comment: @Grizzly and there's nothing to say that you can't compare equality on parts of an object rather than a macocosmic equality function. Obviously, it depends on each use case.

Answer (score 1):

One pointer points to the `Generator` part of the class, the other pointer points to the `Triggerable` part. They can't be the same pointer, because Generator and Triggerable are different.

Answer (score 1):

With multiple inheritance, different base classes can have different memory addresses within the child object.